# C - Printing random numbers from interval

Tags: c, random, numbers

Here's my code, i need it to first say number of 1-10 numbers and then print which ones they are. It gets the number of them right but instead of printing numbers equal to 1-10, it prints first 10 numbers.

```
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int i;
    int br = 0, brr = 0, brrr = 0, br1 = 0;
    int polje[50];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        polje[i] = rand() % 30 + 1;
        printf("%d ", polje[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if(polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10)
            br++;
    }
    printf("Brojevi od 1 do 10 pojavljuju se %d puta a to su ", br);

    do {
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%d ", polje[i]);

    } while (polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try rewriting with english variable names

Comment: Uh Your code looks like it's supposed to be printing the first ten numbers. I don't see where you tell it to only print the numbers among 1 through 10.

Comment: You should change `rand() % 30 + 1;` for `(rand() % 30) + 1;`, `%` has lower priority compared with `+`

Comment: @h3nr1x, that's definitely not true.  `%` has the same precedence as (binary) `*` and `/` - that is, higher than `+`.

Comment: @CarlNorum You're right, sorry, big mistake, my bad

Comment: @tohava: no - there's no need to Anglicize names, especially in code this simple.

Comment: I like variable names `br`, `brr`, `brrr`....... +1 for that!

Comment: Why don't you use a **debugger** and single-step through your code?? That should reveal the problem quickly.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and then print which ones they are

If you need to print **numbers** in the same order as they appear in polje array:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int i;
    int br = 0, brr = 0, brrr = 0, br1 = 0;
    int polje[50];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        polje[i] = rand() % 30 + 1;
        printf("%d ", polje[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if(polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10)
            br++;
    }
    printf("Brojevi od 1 do 10 pojavljuju se %d puta a to su ", br);

    // changed from here:
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if(polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10)
            printf( "%d ", polje[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you need to print **their indexes** (positions) in polje array:

```
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int i;
    int br = 0, brr = 0, brrr = 0, br1 = 0;
    int polje[50];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        polje[i] = rand() % 30 + 1;
        printf("%d ", polje[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if(polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10)
            br++;
    }
    printf("Brojevi od 1 do 10 pojavljuju se %d puta a to su ", br);

    // changed from here:
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if(polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10)
            printf( "%d ", i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code you were looking for. I also took out the do-while loop. It can cause an infinite loop if `polje[10]` was between 1 - 10, because by the time it got to test the condition `i` would forever be 10.

```
for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)  // changed it from 10 to 50
    if((polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10))  // if statement
        printf("%d ", polje[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the numbers between 1 to 10 then here is the corrected version of your code:

```
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int i;
    int br = 0, brr = 0, brrr = 0, br1 = 0;
    int polje[50];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        polje[i] = rand() % 30 + 1;
        printf("%d ", polje[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if(polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10)
            br++;
    }
    printf("\nBrojevi od 1 do 10 pojavljuju se %d puta a to su \n", br);

    //Change the loop from do-while to for and upto 50 iteration instead 10.
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        if(polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10)
             printf("%d ", polje[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**CHANGES:**

> - Replace

```
do {
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%d ", polje[i]);

   } while (polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10);
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    if(polje[i] >= 1 && polje[i] <= 10)
         printf("%d ", polje[i]);
```

as no need of nesting `for loop` inside `while loop`.

> - Change

```
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

to

```
 for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
```

as you have to print all the numbers between 1 to 10 in the array and not only first 10 numbers between 1 to 10 (as per my understanding).